# Using openCV on a UWP Windows 10 Application

Tags: opencv, windows-10, uwp

Is there a way to use OpenCV libraries on a UWP application for Windows 10 without needing to create my own wrappers around openCV or purchasing Emgu CV wrappers? I am aware that there is Android and iOS support (as stated in their page) but no reference for UWP or Windows 8 store apps whatsoever. It just states that Windows is supported.

Comment: Windows supported typically means Winforms/WPF and not WinRT/UWP. Your best bet is to ask it to the creators: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv

Comment: you might want to try [some recent commit](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/5805)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, but I think it is not offical yet, or maybe not finished/tested. It is developed at Microsoft and most of it should be merged into master branch of OpenCV now.

Source: https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/08/20/opencv-support-for-windows-universal-apps-now-available-on-github/#

Initial pull-request with WinRT support: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3700

Comment: the msopentech is closing and merged back with microsoft. do you have any source from within microsoft?