# SInce EmguCV is unavailable for UWP , how can i call c# class/methods from uwp

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, emgucv

Emgucv is not supported in UWP , but i need to use it in my app. Can i create the implementation in C# and call it from UWP somehow ? What is the best approach of this problem ?

Comment: see this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309067/using-opencv-on-a-uwp-windows-10-application .

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest news of the Emgucv [official website](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Windows), Emgu.CV-3.1.0-r16.12 added the UWP support.

> 2016-12-17 Emgu.CV-3.1.0-r16.12 release is available in sourceforge. This version added UWP support for Windows Phone commercial license. See change log and known issues.

So that you could use it in UWP. Fortunately, there is an official sample for UWP already, please reference [Emgu.CV.Example/RealtimeCamera.UWP](https://github.com/neutmute/emgucv/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example/RealtimeCamera.UWP).

Comment: ok but in the example , they dont reference umgucv , but somehow manage to use cvExtern..Also Emgu.CV-3.1.0-r16.12 is not on nugget , and downloading in from sourceforge i cannot use it in UWP